# Could we please detect troublesome questions using Stack Overflow data and offload them to Triage review for an hour or two?

Tags: feature-request, questions, review, stackoverflow, low-quality-posts

Propose to detect troublesome questions using Stack Overflow quality scoring data and put them to [Triage queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage) for an hour or two. If the timeout expires before decision is made, let questions go to homepage.

As for the questions that fail the Triage, one option to handle these is to keep them invisible for a day or two (if not edited), then automatically [bump](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/bump/info) them for a broader community review. This way would keep them away from the top of [newest tab](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest). (Attentive readers may notice that bumps imply certain pollution of [active tab](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active) but this looks less of an issue to me, as this tab is rather heavily dominated by better questions being bumped by answers and edits. Not to mention that Triage would spare active page from questions deserving flagging for speedy deletion - spam, [homework dumps](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3837/31260), ["cubicle fart"](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6677/31260) kind stuff...)

Reasons why I consider above approach feasible are [laid out here](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7251/31260):

> goal, about ["wall of crap"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258699/the-stack-overflow-homepage-is-over-emphasizing-bad-questions-and-a-proposed-so) at homepage, also looks relevant to us, as indicated by multiple recurring discussions about [too many bad questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/7130?lq=1).
>
> ...site topics substantially overlap and... many troublesome questions over here appear to be posted by users who are simply [trying to circumvent question block at Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7020/31260). Using same scoring data that is supposed to detect and block them at Stack Overflow would make sense, wouldn't it?
>
> ...there is just no way to ensure that questions in Triage queue would be reviewed within reasonable timeframe... automatically kick questions off this queue and let them go to homepage after some timeout (say, 1-2 hours) if these haven't got sufficient attention.

---

Related:

- [Is this site failing? And should it go away?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7906/is-there-something-wrong-with-this-sites-rules-for-posting-questions)
- [Why are we getting so many off topic 'debug this for me' questions? what can we do about it?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7614/why-are-we-getting-so-many-off-topic-debug-this-for-me-questions-what-can-we)
- [Is there any point in this site still existing?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7593/is-there-any-point-in-this-site-still-existing)
  <sup>Note this one even suggests Stack Overflow (protected by Triage!) as an example of how a site should look like.</sup>
- [So many bad questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7130/so-many-bad-questions)
- [There are way more negative votes in the top 50 questions than positive. Time to think](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7239/there-are-way-more-negative-votes-in-the-top-50-questions-than-positive-time-to)
- ['Problem' and 'help' titles in off-topic questions of new users coming from Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7221/problem-titles-in-off-topic-questions-of-new-users-coming-from-stack-overflow)
- [Let's help askers who are trying to circumvent question block at Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7020/lets-help-askers-who-are-trying-to-circumvent-question-block-at-stack-overflow)
- [Why can't we raise up questions quality?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6990/why-cant-we-raise-up-questions-quality)
- [How effective is the quality filter against this question with all-caps brief title and text?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6850/how-effective-is-the-quality-filter-against-this-question-with-all-caps-brief-ti)
- [A lot of front page down votes](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6788/a-lot-of-front-page-down-votes)
- [Cutting down on off topic posts](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6711/cutting-down-on-off-topic-posts)
- [How many questions do we get from users recently blocked at SO, how many of these are closed / deleted?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6592/how-many-questions-do-we-get-from-users-recently-blocked-at-so-how-many-of-thes)
- [Why so many negative votes here?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6376/why-so-many-negative-votes-here)
- [How can we encourage people to read the FAQ before asking their first question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6371/how-can-we-encourage-people-to-read-the-faq-before-asking-their-first-question)
- [How can we avoid turning off potential participants who see the wall of Closed questions?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6241/how-can-we-avoid-turning-off-potential-participants-who-see-the-wall-of-closed-q)
- [Why are there so many closed, on hold, and down voted questions here?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6233/why-are-there-so-many-closed-on-hold-and-down-voted-questions-here)
- [Better Selection / Title for Top Questions List](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5618/better-selection-title-for-top-questions-list)
- [Requiring registration to ask questions - did it made a difference?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5377/requiring-registration-to-ask-questions-did-it-made-a-difference)
- [Why are there so many minus points on questions in this site?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4029/why-are-there-so-many-minus-points-on-questions-in-this-site)
- [Programmers Stack Exchange question downvoting, what to do?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4009/programmers-stack-exchange-question-downvoting-what-to-do)
- [What can we do about extremely low quality questions from unregistered users?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3947/what-can-we-do-about-extremely-low-quality-questions-from-unregistered-users)
- [Can we have some way to not show closed questions on the front page?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3778/can-we-have-some-way-to-not-show-closed-questions-on-the-front-page)
- [What can we do to help users understand our site better?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3551/what-can-we-do-to-help-users-understand-our-site-better)
- [What can be done about bad questions on Programmers?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2851/what-can-be-done-about-bad-questions-on-programmers)
- [How can I create a custom filtered view of questions?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2744/how-can-i-create-a-custom-filtered-view-of-questions)
- [Are we scaring off new users?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2727/are-we-scaring-off-new-users)
- [Why are so many questions closed?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2570/why-are-so-many-questions-closed) (Nov 17 '11)

  - [Why are so many questions closed?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4097/why-are-so-many-questions-closed) (Oct 8 '12)
- [What to do about the proliferation of bad questions from generic accounts?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1589/what-to-do-about-the-proliferation-of-bad-questions-from-generic-accounts)
- [Why are almost half the questions on the front page marked "closed"?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/841/why-are-almost-half-the-questions-on-the-front-page-marked-closed)
- [Are we closing too many good questions now?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/784/are-we-closing-too-many-good-questions-now)

Comment: For the first time on SE, I seriously wish I could upvote something more than once.

Comment: The only issue that I have with this is that these questions are *already getting triaged;* the small number of people on Programmers who are actively curating the site already see these questions, discuss them in The Whiteboard, and vote to close them.

Comment: **Small rant:** more people should get involved with this process instead of spending their time pontificating over a site name change/clarification which is never going to happen and which won't stop the bad questions anyway.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I see. I think a lot depends on how good is SO quality scoring. If it manages to reliably pick triage-worthy questions, this may even help _expand_ current group of "active triagers". You see, current way is much based on personal trust and I for one can understand reluctance of not very involved site regulars joining it (_"who's that guy Robert Harvey and why does he freaks out about this question"_). System-based, automatic, "unbiased" triage selection could lower this barrier for participation

Comment: One of the principal motivators for a triage queue is the sheer number of questions that Stack Overflow gets, a dynamic that does not exist here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey [28 linked questions](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/7257?lq=1) suggest that we've got our own "dynamics" in these

Comment: @gnat: We get that many bad questions on SO in a 30 minute window.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I know. I doubt though that it's what SO regulars really see (who in their sane mind would look at unfiltered questions page over there). Folks look through tag pages, and these are often closer in traffic (and in amount of garbage, respectively) to Programmers

Comment: ...300+ upvotes to that famous [wall of cr@p](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258699/the-stack-overflow-homepage-is-over-emphasizing-bad-questions-and-a-proposed-so) complaint at MSO could easily be from tag regulars who discovered that what bothers them at their "local" tag pages is actually a site wide problem

Comment: Most of the bad questions seem to come from those with reputation of exactly 1.  There should be a way of helping noobs without polluting the main site.  Sometimes they need direction to FAQs, other times, to other sites.